# How to find the table name which the image randomly selected from

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query to randomly select 6 images from 3 SQL tables in same database and once someone clicked on that image I want to send them to separate page according from what table that image is selected from. To do that by the query I want to find out the table name which that random image was selected.

My SQL query is

```
$sql="SELECT *
FROM   salehotel
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   saleland
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM   salehouse
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
?>
<?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {?>
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 10px;">
        <a href="sale_house_detail.php?id=<?php echo $row['property_id'];  ?>">
            <img src=<?= '"admin/uploads/'.$row['image1'].'"'; ?> width="172px" height="149px" style='border:5px solid  #CCC' />
        </a>
    <p><?php  echo $row['Type']; ?></p>
    <p><?php  echo $row['Location']; ?></p>
  </div>

    <?php   }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new field that indicates the source table in your SQL:

```
$sql="SELECT salehotel.*, 'salehotel' as source
FROM   salehotel
UNION ALL
SELECT saleland.*, 'saleland' as source
FROM   saleland
UNION ALL
SELECT salehouse.*, 'salehouse' as source
FROM   salehouse
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
";
```

Your PHP can then show this column as:

```
<?php  echo $row['source']; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the table name in your query:

```
SELECT 'salehotel' as which, sh.*
FROM   salehotel sh
UNION ALL
SELECT 'saleland' as which, sl.*
FROM   saleland sl
UNION ALL
SELECT 'salehouse' as which, sho.*
FROM   salehouse sho
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6
```

Then change the php code appropriately to handle the extra column.

Answer (score 1):

How about `select *, 'table_name'` as a field and then use that column to send them to the appropriate place.