# mysql - find table name from SELECT statement over multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

A query is made to select rows from multiple tables... Then necessary info (i.e `headline` is retrieved from there )

```
$sql="(SELECT `headline`,`date` FROM `arts`)

UNION

(SELECT `headline`,`date` FROM `lead_news`)

UNION

(SELECT `headline`,`date` FROM `opinion_analysis`)

UNION

(SELECT `headline`,`date` FROM `politics`)

UNION

(SELECT `headline`,`date` FROM `top_news`)

UNION

(SELECT `headline`,`date` FROM `lifestyle`)

ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $limit  ";
```

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['headline']));
}
```

I also need to  find out the `table` name for each `$row`.  I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544758/how-to-find-the-table-name-which-the-image-randomly-selected-from) that suggests the query to be :

`"SELECT *, table_name as source FROM table_name"` so that `$row['source']` can return the table name.

But I am trying to know whether there is  any associative array key to retrieve the name from `$row` or any built-in function in mysql ?

**EDIT** : I wrote the `SELECT` commands in the following way :

```
SELECT `headline`,`date`, `arts` as `source` FROM `arts`
```

and got the error :Unknown column 'arts' in 'field list'.
What way to adopt here ?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of [How to find the table name which the image randomly selected from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544758/how-to-find-the-table-name-which-the-image-randomly-selected-from). The solution there is the solution. I don't see what else exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: let me visit the suggested link

Comment: Looks more like wrong structured database. Dont use deprecated mysql calls.

Comment: @WigglerJtag, which one is deprecated ?

Comment: Which table name should display in case of one row from two tables?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: @deceze, I want to know whether there is any built-in associative array index key (suppose `related_table_name`) so that `$row[related_table_name']` could be used .. or any other built in function so that I do not have to manually add the table name in each `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @shola, one row from two tables -- cannot understand ..

Comment: it might same row from two table and resulted show one as union in query

Comment: You want to know whether there's a way to get the table name without including a `'tablename' as source` in the query? No, there isn't.

Comment: @deceze That is exactly what i wanted to know. Is the question worth downvote?

Comment: @deceze, do you have any answer to what shola said ?

Comment: You don't have a *downvote*. Consider `SELECT "foo" UNION SELECT "bar"`. That query will return two rows, both of which have nothing to do with any physical table. Query results are not related to any tables, there is no function to extract "origin metadata" from a result.

Comment: Query mentioned in question select headline and date and in case result of query from two table might same then it will show only one in that case which table name will need to display

Comment: @deceze, added an Edit.

Comment: @shaola, the table the data is fetched from .. Any way to show both rows even of they are exactly same and are from two different tables ?

Comment: can you try below it will give one row only:
select 'Hello'
UNION
select 'Hello'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `headline`,`date`, 'arts' as `source` FROM `arts`
```

You want to select *the string* "arts", hence put it in `'` quotes, not backticks.

But really, your table design seems *very* wrong. Unless all these items are extremely different, you should have *one* table with a column `category` (or similar), not one table for each category.

Comment: Actually they store news items ... each news category has its own table.

Comment: That's what deceze is trying to say.  If they are all news items, you should have ONE table with NEWS ITEMS.  Add another field called "category".

Comment: @JNovack, suppose there are thousands of news posts in arts, politics and sports categories... So when I want to fetch the most recent 10 entries of politics, isn't it better to store them in separate tables rather than in a single one ? In course of time the unified table might grow larger posing the speed performance issu.

Comment: @deceze, I explained the reason behind the entries being in separate tables in my comment to JNovack.

Comment: @Istiaque A properly configured database with properly *indexed* tables can easily handle millions if not billions of entries! If you ever get to the point where you have problems because you have too much data, congratulate yourself on a job well done.

Comment: Oh I see.. hmm... so why to call that of mine a bad design ? Does it cause any performance issue?

Comment: @deceze, can you please include your comment gist in your answer that no such way is there ?